# How do I resolve missing plugin error when trying to add to a Firebase data?

Tags: flutter, firebase

MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#set on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore))

On this line of code:

```
Future addUserDetails(String username) async {
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
  'username': username,
});
```

}
Could anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you follow the complete installation setup? If yes, just do 'flutter clean' then 'flutter pub get' on your project folder. Remove app from emulator and do a clean install. Might fix your problems.

Comment: share ur pubspec.yaml file

Comment: name: proj1
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.3 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.10.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.9

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  fonts:
    - family: Montserrat
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Italic.ttf

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - images/